# Testing Silverlight Installation Experience

Tags: web-development, usability, testing, silverlight

In my web app I use Silverlight. Since I already have Silverlight installed I cannot test how my webapp behaves in case a user has no Silverlight installed, or has old version of it, or their computer has configuration which is incompatible with Silverlight at all.

Is there a recommended approach in reproducing these types of environments for testing purposes, or the only way is to delete/install browser many times?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have multiple machines for testing, you can probably get away with installing an alternate browser you don't have.  [Netscape Navigator](http://browser.netscape.com/releases) still exists, along with a [pile of others](http://browsers.evolt.org/).

Also, consider setting your PC up to dual-boot Ubuntu (assuming you're using Windows, since it's Silverlight) if it's not already.  It isn't too tricky as long as you can spare the disk space and keep a just-in-case backup nearby. It's worth the effort for anyone involved in web dev.

For realistic testing though, invest in multiple machines or lure/hire some friends in to help out. It's not cheap to keep up with every OS upgrade & new super-phone out there, but it's definitely nice to not ever have to guess.